# Displaying custom error page at startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Is there a way to display a custom error page when an exception occurs during the startup phase of an ASP.NET Core application? For example, if an exception occurs (db is down etc.) in any of the methods of the Startup class i.e. Configure, ConfigureServices, Startup.Ctor etc.?
I think that using the following code isn't going to help me

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseStatusCodePages();
    app.UseBrowserLink();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}
```

as the middleware pipline isn't constructed yet. So the line

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
```

isn't executed as a consequence.
Is there a way to display a custom error page if an error occurs at this stage?

thanks
ashilon

Comment: OK, didn't know about that. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Configure` method you're configuring the HTTP pipeline to handle requests. Since there is no request when your application starts, the pipeline is never executed. In fact, as you mentioned the exception might occur when you're actually configuring the pipeline.

The hosting layer provides a way to capture startup errors and show a decent error page. You can use the `CaptureStartupErrors(true)` on the `IWebHostBuilder` interface. This is where you configure the hosting layer of your application and is typically located in `Pogram.cs`. For example:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseApplicationInsights()
        .CaptureStartupErrors(captureStartupErrors: true) // Add this line
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Very helpful. Thank you Henk.

Comment: @henk-mollema You mention showing a custom error page for startup errors, what's the recommended way of specifying this to avoid the default:"An error occurred while starting the application"? Is it defined on the Host config as well?

Comment: @TallMcPaul I have the same question =(

Answer (score -2):

For a simple approach, you can have a script block that contains alert("your error message"). If you want the popup to be styled as the rest of your website then you could render your error message into a div element and use a jQuery dialog to display it as a modal dialog within your page, then you just need to put it in your code :D , hope this helps!

Comment: I don't think this addresses the question. I think Ashilon is referring to a .core equivalent of `Globals.asax` to handle the error, or to override `OnException` like in MVC ?

Comment: I'm sorry Horacio, but Daniel Shillocock is right. I'm talking about ASP.NET Core here, and like Daniel mentioned, something similar to Gloabl.asax and OnException in MVC. Only that the scenation described occurs early in the application startup process, so the middleware infrastrcutrue isn't in place yet. Thanks anyways.

Comment: This is just a vague description of an answer, not an answer. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)